# how to check hooks on React Native Debugger

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

When using react for web, the state of the hooks can be checked on the browser using the `React dev Tools`

now, on react native, I have some hooks, but can't find how to check their state on the `React Native Debugger` on chrome.

How to check the hooks for a react native project?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is under the Components tab

Click on the component that contains hooks on the left side

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had to install the "React Native Debugger", it works as you commented, but on the browser it doesn't show, thanks again!